# Can't return mysql db query results in Netlify Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, netlify

I am working off [a netlify demo project repo](https://functions-playground.netlify.com/) I added a new lambda function `mytest.js`.

In `mytest` I am connecting to a mysql db and trying to return the results of the query.

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const pool = mysql.createPool({ ...config data... })

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

  try {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM mytable order by DatePublished desc', function(error, results, fields) {
        connection.release()

          if (error) {
            console.log('calling callback with error')
            callback(error);
          }
          else {
            console.log(`calling callback with results`)
            console.log(results);
            callback(null, {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: results
            })
          }             
      })
    })
  } 
  catch (e) {
      console.log('errored in try catch')
      console.log(e)
  } 
}
```

When I deploy this and hit the url, I can see the query to the db is successful and I see the results logged out (in the netlify web ui logs) but returning the data always results in a 502.

I tried the same thing in postman and got nothing back in the body.

When I hard code `body: 'test string'` it will return "test string" correctly so I know the function otherwise works so I am really confused as to why the results are available when they are logged but not in the callback.

`results` in the log is an array of 208 pretty simple objects with about 7 properties each all of which are small data like ints and url strings

Any help with this would be appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE AFTER ACCEPTED ANSWER - also added CORS headers because that came up afterward**

```
        callback(null, {
          statusCode: 200,
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(results)
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using JSON.stringify on the results, the body should be a string.

Comment: Its times like these that humble me so much. I can't believe I overlooked something like this. I even tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)) but it never crossed my mind to try to stringify the results. Thank you so much